# Facebook like chat system using JSF(Prime faces modal dialog)

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Is it possible to build a facebook like chat system using JSF(Primefaces modal popup). I have managed to build a single modal dialog box using primefaces. I want to know if it is possible to add multiple modal
dialog boxes using primefaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/chat.jsf. The functionality seems to exist for building something like what you want.